# How indexOf is implemented in Node?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, performance

I am searching for the best data structure and the fastest algorithm to know if a value exists amongst unsorted data in memory assuming that the distribution is random.

The program is intended to run on Node.

I had 9 candidates to test:

1. array indexOf
2. array find
3. array findIndex
4. for of loop break
5. for x++ loop break
6. set has
7. map has
8. object property call
9. object in

Here are the results:

[image]

Initially, I thought that the methods 1->5 would *traverse* the array whereas the methods 6->9 would use *hashtables* to look up the values more efficiently.

Most of the results were showed up as expected.

The fastest method is using a `Map` and its `Map.has` method.

However, what made me curious was the method `indexOf` for `Array`.

Why does it take less time than a for loop with a break?

In the result, it took **1970 ms** to run but other `array` *traverse* methods took between **13217 ms** to  **20124 ms** to run. That's a lot of difference.

I also don't think it uses hashtable because all method that used hashtable took only **36ms** maximum to run.

Hence, I am curious to know what is the algorithm behind `indexOf` of Array? (I already searched on Google but I only found documentation about its usage, little about its implementation and even less on its implementation on Node)

```
import 'mocha';
import {assert} from 'chai';

describe('should test search performance', function () {

    const N = 50000

    const array: string[] = []
    const object: { [id: string]: boolean } = {}
    const set: Set<string> = new Set()
    const map: Map<string, boolean> = new Map()

    for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        const value = Math.random().toString()
        array.push(value)
        object[value] = true
        set.add(value)
        map.set(value, true)
    }

    const T = 100000

    it('test  1. array indexOf ', async () => {
        const start = new Date().getTime()
        for (let x = 0; x < T; x++) {

            const searchIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
            const search = array[searchIndex];
            const found = array.indexOf(search)
            // assert(found > -1)

        }
        const diff = new Date().getTime() - start
        console.log(`Took: ${diff} ms`);

    }).timeout(60 * 1000);

    it('test  1. array find ', async () => {
        const start = new Date().getTime()
        for (let x = 0; x < T; x++) {

            const searchIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
            const search = array[searchIndex];
            const found = array.find((item) => {
                return item === search
            })
            assert(found === search)

        }
        const diff = new Date().getTime() - start
        console.log(`Took: ${diff} ms`);

    }).timeout(60 * 1000);

    it('test  1. array findIndex ', async () => {
        const start = new Date().getTime()
        for (let x = 0; x < T; x++) {

            const searchIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
            const search = array[searchIndex];
            const found = array.findIndex((item) => {
                return item === search
            })
            assert(found > -1)

        }
        const diff = new Date().getTime() - start
        console.log(`Took: ${diff} ms`);

    }).timeout(60 * 1000);

    it('test  1. for of loop break ', async () => {
        const start = new Date().getTime()
        for (let x = 0; x < T; x++) {

            const searchIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
            const search = array[searchIndex];
            let found = false
            for (const item of array) {
                if (item === search) {
                    found = true
                    break
                }
            }
            // assert(found === true)
        }
        const diff = new Date().getTime() - start
        console.log(`Took: ${diff} ms`);

    }).timeout(60 * 1000);

    it('test  1. for x++ loop break ', async () => {
        const start = new Date().getTime()
        for (let x = 0; x < T; x++) {

            const searchIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
            const search = array[searchIndex];
            let found = false
            for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (array[i] === search) {
                    found = true
                    break
                }
            }
            // assert(found === true)
        }
        const diff = new Date().getTime() - start
        console.log(`Took: ${diff} ms`);

    }).timeout(60 * 1000);

    it('test  1. set has', async () => {
        const start = new Date().getTime()
        for (let x = 0; x < T; x++) {

            const searchIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
            const search = array[searchIndex];
            const found = set.has(search)
            // assert(found === true)
        }
        const diff = new Date().getTime() - start
        console.log(`Took: ${diff} ms`);

    }).timeout(60 * 1000);

    it('test  1. map has', async () => {
        const start = new Date().getTime()
        for (let x = 0; x < T; x++) {

            const searchIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
            const search = array[searchIndex];
            const found = map.has(search)
            // assert(found === true)
        }
        const diff = new Date().getTime() - start
        console.log(`Took: ${diff} ms`);

    }).timeout(60 * 1000);

    it('test  1. object property call', async () => {
        const start = new Date().getTime()
        for (let x = 0; x < T; x++) {

            const searchIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
            const search = array[searchIndex];
            const found = object[search]
            // assert(found === true)
        }
        const diff = new Date().getTime() - start
        console.log(`Took: ${diff} ms`);

    }).timeout(60 * 1000);

    it('test  1. object in', async () => {
        const start = new Date().getTime()
        for (let x = 0; x < T; x++) {

            const searchIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
            const search = array[searchIndex];
            const found = search in object
            // assert(found === true)
        }
        const diff = new Date().getTime() - start
        console.log(`Took: ${diff} ms`);

    }).timeout(60 * 1000);
})
```

Comment: *Why does it take less time than a for loop with a break?* Mainly because it's implemented in native code, I'd think

Comment: As far as I know, it's rather matter of `v8`, where indexOf should be natively implemented (on fixed arrays). Also, the operating system matters, you may encounter different results according to the OS the compiled code is running on. https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4b9b23521e6fd42373ebbcb20ebe03bf445494f9/src/objects/fixed-array-inl.h